# Selfinjective algebras with loops

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Given a selfinjective finite dimensional algebra $A$ with an indecomposable module $M$ with $Ext_A^1(M,M) \neq 0$.

> Question:
>
> Is A derived equivalent to an algebra with a loop in the quiver in case $M$ is uniserial? (I believe this should be true for example for Brauer tree algebras and maybe general representation-finite selfinjective algebras)